How to pass arguments(labels) to map function map_func, callable from tf.data.Dataset.map() in Python
There is known method how to create dataset:
CODE snippet was borrowed from: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/simple_audio
#Gather data from files
'''
.....some code I see no need to paste, see link above for full code........
'''
#Create map-function

def get_label(file_path):
  parts = tf.strings.split(
      input=file_path,
      sep=os.path.sep)
  # Note: You'll use indexing here instead of tuple unpacking to enable this
  # to work in a TensorFlow graph.
  return parts[-2]

#MAP FUNCTION!!!!!
def get_waveform_and_label(file_path):
  label = get_label(file_path)
  audio_binary = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  waveform = decode_audio(audio_binary)
  return waveform, label

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

#create dataset
files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_files)


#And the most common method to label each data in dataset is using tf.data.Dataset.map():
waveform_ds = files_ds.map(
    map_func=get_waveform_and_label,
    num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

for element in waveform_ds:
  print(element)

After print execution any element shows such kind of data(I took random couple of dataset line "waveform_ds"):
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(16000,), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([ 9.1552734e-05,  1.5258789e-04,  2.4414062e-04, ...,
-3.3569336e-04, -3.6621094e-04, -2.4414062e-04], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'right'>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(16000,), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([ 0.0010376 ,  0.00097656,  0.00094604, ..., -0.00183105,
-0.00158691, -0.00152588], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'no'>)

Two questions:
1. How does tf.data.Dataset.map() function figure out what kind of label am I going to pass, if there is no args to pass to "get_waveform_and_label" in ... .Dataset.map()?
2. And what I have to do, if I want to use my own labels, defined in list, tuple or dict NOT FROM FILE PATH FOLDERS as many tutorials and code snippet above do? For example:
my_labels = ['relaxation', 'grip', 'ungrip']

So Is there any other way except putting my_labels as constant value in map function "get_waveform_and_label"?
That code below is not main, thats for section "what I try to do to solve problem", "maplabel" written bad, "label" receives one of "my_labels" item, RaggedTensor 'timeframes' is actually the array, that stores simple tensors, like:
tf.Tensor(
[[0.5369535 0.2724565 0.073154  ... 0.0074817 0.2035824 0.0882927]
 [0.5376732 0.2733304 0.0730333 ... 0.0017834 0.1970369 0.0859187]
 [0.5307747 0.2692053 0.0720603 ... 0.0029357 0.1989727 0.0866213]
 ...
 [0.5395046 0.2826822 0.0747677 ... 0.0085316 0.1982029 0.0849934]
 [0.5299433 0.2774992 0.073246  ... 0.0083179 0.1994617 0.085429 ]
 [0.5329857 0.278462  0.0736021 ... 0.0070133 0.2008929 0.0860079]], shape=(117, 128), dtype=float64)

tf.Tensor(
[[0.5278226 0.27012   0.0709168 ... 0.0110207 0.1954106 0.0877619]
 [0.5296971 0.2716435 0.0712691 ... 0.005279  0.1967631 0.0881876]
 [0.5316442 0.2725459 0.0716114 ... 0.0044511 0.1991368 0.089243 ]
 ...
 [0.5419291 0.2776711 0.0726136 ... 0.0114332 0.1941741 0.0884957]
 [0.5319294 0.2723156 0.071426  ... 0.010159  0.1962118 0.0891404]
 [0.5338816 0.2737131 0.0718814 ... 0.0103788 0.1974683 0.0897296]], shape=(118, 128), dtype=float64)


_def maplabel(dataset, tensored_label):
    return dataset, tensored_label

def get_timeFrames_with_label(timeframes:tf.RaggedTensor, \
                              label:str):

    samplesCount = timeframes.shape[0]
    dataset_lines = [None] * samplesCount
    str_tensors = [None] * samplesCount

    
    for i in range(samplesCount):
        dataset_lines[i] = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(timeframes[i])
        str_tensors[i] = tf.constant(label, dtype=tf.string)
    
    com1tframes_ds = tf.data.Dataset.choose_from_datasets(dataset_lines,\    tf.data.Dataset.range(samplesCount))
    #command_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(str_tensors) 
    #...Dataset.zip(com1tframes_ds, command_ds) gives error "command_ds has no function
    #string.isidentifier"
    
    com1tframes_ds.map(map_func=maplabel(com1tframes_ds, label), \
                       num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)_


When you call files_ds.map(map_func=get_waveform_and_label) object files_ds passes its every line one by one. In your case of voice recognition files_ds Dataset object stores a lines of string binary(with b prefix) lines. Thus files_ds will pass self as an argument and if self have structure of string only - it will pass each string as a signature. But if files_ds have a structure of Dataset like this: (1, 'grip') object files_ds will a;ready pass to map function two arguments. Thus number and type of arguments only depends on tf.data.Dataset inner structure you or other programmer have made

And pay attention to the thing that voice recognition tensores stores NUMPY-ed type of data: <tf.Tensor: shape=(16000,), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([ 0.0010376 ,  0.00097656,  0.00094604, ..., -0.00183105,
-0.00158691, -0.00152588], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'no'>. I have no idea how to made it other way, than voice recognition proposes
